# Cancelling the downvote lead to +2 not +5

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

I have a question on voting system of SO. So I have seen a trend among some community members that they prefer to first downvote 
the question and then point out the corrections they were hoping to see in the comments section and once it's done and they cancel their
downvote.

No problems in that except that as I have read in the Reputation system of SO, it is written that on cancelling the downvote to the 
question you will be awarded +2. That means there is a net loss of 3 reputation. Now the thing is, judging the quality of the question is
a subjective thing. This could lead to good loss of reputation of OP. I don't think many community members know of this rule.

Today I faced this situation. Though the member didn't intentionally wanted to create me a loss of reputation, but it did. I think a 
little hovering message while downvoting can go a long way to prevent this.

Comment: "That means there is a net loss of 3 reputation." - how exactly does that mean this?

Comment: A downvote will take 2 rep from the OP, not 5. An _upvote_ will _give_ you 5 rep, but a downvote only takes 2. Therefore, when a downvote is removed... You get 2 rep back. (Likewise, a removed upvote will take 5 rep from you.)

Comment: "a little hovering message while downvoting can go a long way to prevent this" - first, I don't know what exactly you mean to prevent, second - what would this message look like?

Answer (score 7):

You misread something.

While upvote gives +5 reputation, a downvote takes away 2 reputation (i.e. cause -2) and not a -5 as you somehow thought.

So when  downvote is undone, the user who was downvoted get those -2 back, meaning a +2.

There is no reputation loss here, everything works as expected.

If you see a "-3" in your reputation history for a specific question, it probably means there is one upvote (+5) and four downvotes (-8) and it doesn't mean a downvote that was undone caused that -3.